# Java's "public static final Object" in C++

Tags: java, c++

What would be the equivalent of this in C++ of the following snippet. I am in the process converting parts of an java application to C++.

Here is that java class snippet:

```
class container {
  Public static final Object CONTAINER_FULL = new Object {
     public boolean equals(Object other) {
        // ...
     }
     String toString() {
        // ...
     }
     // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

The above class is wrapped in an java interface class "container".
The call is ...

```
public Object fetch_the_object(int at_pos) {
     if (at_pos == MAX) {
        return container.CONTAINER_FULL;
     } 
     // ...
}
```

What would be the closest equivalent in C++ of that static class and its call?

Comment: What is the purpose of the container class? What kind of thing does it represent? What problem is it intended to solve?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't directly translate into C++, which is a very different language. Perhaps if you'd explain what you actually need, then someone could provide C++ code to do that.

Comment: The class where that public static object is located is an interface class. The implementation of that is a class of an array containing strings including NULL at the end of string. Say, the fetch_the_object() returns an item (based on the passed index at_pos) from the array, if the end of end of string (or NULL) is reached) then CONTAINER_FULL Object is returned.
The toString() function in that static class return string("end") and the equals method compares the passed object with the this (CONTAINER_FULL) object, if equal, it retuns a CONTAINER_FULL object.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Thing
 {
    public:
      static const OtherThing CONTAINER_FULL;
 };
 const OtherThing Thing::CONTAINER_FULL = blah;
```

Constant, static, non-integral data types must be defined outside the class body. If you want OtherThing to be anything, change it to

```
void *
```

Comment: Their definitions should also generally be in implementation file (.cc, .cpp) rather than in the header.

Comment: Yes, indeed Tronic. The example here is with brevity in mind, but would certainly work.

Comment: And the toString Function would be implemented as an C++ operator<< checking for that object?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
struct Container {
    struct Full {
        ...
    };
    static const Full full;
};
```

Comment: I think in C++ it would be somekind like a wrapper class arround that array (see my commeent above). Everytime a NULL (end of sentnce) is reached, that object is returned. CONTAINER_FULL in string representation (or that toString method) is "end". But I am not sure yet ....